# How to make sure $http.get in service completes before directive is initialized with data?

Tags: angularjs

How do I make it such that all the data "MyService" needs to retrieve is retrieved before my 'control' directive is created or some function to actually add those items is called? If not, is there some other recommended way involving controllers, etc. Have yet to see a basic example of similar sequence. Note that data may have more values added to it via other functions, in which a method would have to be called explicitly for those new data elements.

Service:

```
// var app = angular.module...
app.service('MyService', function($http) {
    this.data = [];

    // Called once to first initalize the data
    $http.get('data.json').then(function data(response) {
      this.data.push(response);        
    } 
})
```

Directive (with its own isolate controller? or point to the main app controller)?:

```
myDirective.directive('control', ['Params', 'MyService', function(Params, MyService) {
     // Call on a method "addData(MyService.data) when the data is actually loaded
}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to stop directive form initiating and wait for a async function call of a service. However, several alternatives here:

#### 1. Use ng-route and set up a resolve with `$routeProvider`.

API: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider

Basically, you return a promise in a route's resolver, the route's view will wait for that promise to resolve. After resolve, it will load the view and initiate whatever controller or directive within the view.

#### 2. `$watch` the `data` property of `MyService`.

When `data` changes, do whatever you want

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return MyService.data;
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
  // do something
}, true);
```

#### 3. Trigger a `ready` event on `MyService`, listen to MyService in your directive.

This requires you to include some event library such as 'EventEmitter`, and mix it into MyService.

#### 4. `$broadcast` ready event on `$rootScope` from MyService, and listen to it in your directive.

```
app.service('MyService', function($http, $rootScope) {
    this.data = [];
    var _this = this;

    // Called once to first initalize the data
    $http.get('data.json').then(function data(response) {
      _this.data.push(response);
      $rootScope.$broadcast('MyServiceReady');
    } 
})


myDirective.directive('control', ['Params', 'MyService', function(Params, MyService) {
    return function(scope) {
      scope.$on('MyServiceReady', function() {
        // do something
      });
    };
}]);
```